# How to sort posts by views of current category in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want top 5 posts by views on current category in wordpress. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have meta value with views count you can change your query:

```
$query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,  
    'meta_key' => 'views_count_field_name',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
```

With this args WordPress will get only 5 posts that have views and sort them by higher value. Change `views_count_field_name` by your meta field name.

Comment: I don't have meta value with views. How can I implement it?